# $\int \frac{1}{|z|}\ dz$ over the curve $\alpha(t) = re^{it}$, $t\in [0,2\pi]$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

In order to calculate

$$\int \frac{1}{|z|}\ dz$$

over the circumference $\alpha(t) = re^{it}$, $t\in [0,2\pi]$

I cannot use the theorem that says that this integral is determined by its end points, because $\frac{1}{|z|}$ is not analytic in $z=0$ which is contained inside the contour. So I did it by definition:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{|r||e^{it}|}ire^{it}\ dt = \int_0^{2\pi} ire^{it}\ dt = r(e^{i\cdot 2\pi}-e^0) = 0$$

but I got $0$, which should be the result if I were using the theorem. Is my integral right?

Comment: It is correct. You can in fact use the theorem here after noticing that the integrand is constant over the contour so it's just like if you are integrating the function $f(z) = 1/r = {\rm constant}$ which is analytic.

Comment: Do you know $r>0$?  ... or at least $r \neq 0$?

Comment: @Winther but I couldn't use the theorem for a complex funciton, right? Also, for your integral of $\frac{1}{r}$, what are the intervals of integration?

Comment: More accurately: if we define $g(z) = 1/r = {\rm constant}$ and $f(z) = 1/|z|$ then we have $f(z) = g(z)$ along the contour $C$ you are integrating over so we have $\oint_C f(z){\rm d}z = \oint_C g(z){\rm d}z$. This latter integral is zero by the theorem you mention since $g(z)$ is an entire function (analytical everywhere) and the contour is closed. The integration limits for the $g$ integral is the same as for the $f$ integral and you can evaluate it just as you did in your approach. Anyway I'm not saying you have to solve it this way, the way you have done it is perfectly fine.